# Using Bearer Token In modheader

Tags: http, request, header

I know modheader extension allows us to modify the header of a request. And as such we can handle authorization use cases by specifying Token. But what I've seen so far is the use of basic tokens. My question is : Does modheader allow us to specify Bearer Token as in tools like Postman or Thunder Client ? If Yes then how to do it ? Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works using the header Name "Authorization" and the value "Bearer YOURTOKEN"

[Header configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rkVq.png)

Comment: Waoh :)) Thanks a lot It does work now that I did it as shown in the image